# Hazelcast dynamic member addition

Tags: hazelcast

We want to form Hazel cast cluster at server restart. at server start it will find IP address and add member in hazel cast cluster.

please provide any help on approach.

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration is multicast. If this is enabled by your network administrators machines should find each other for you. But it may be
deactivated so you'd need to do another way.

An easy way is TCP discovery,
configuration (if you use YAML) something like:

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      tcp-ip:
        enabled: true
        member-list:
          - 12.34.56.78:5701
          - 34.56.78.12:5701
          - 56.78.12.34:5701
```

When the process starts, it will try those addresses (ignoring if one is itself) to see if anything is there. If it, it'll cluster together.

If you don't know your IPs in advance, you can pass them in as arguments and et them from Java.

```
JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = new TcpIpConfig();
tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true);
tcpIpConfig.setMembers(List.of("12.34.56.78:5701", "34.56.78.12:5701"));
joinConfig.setTcpIpConfig(tcpIpConfig);
```